# Load a 3D .mat file as a grayscale numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert a 3D image into a numpy array, making sure to preserve the fact that it is a grayscale image.

I have created an empty array in which I would like to load these images into where x,y,z, are the respective dimensions and channels = 1.

```
img_array = np.ndarray((len(directory), x, y, z, channels), dtype=np.uint8
```

This is the code I used to convert the original .mat files to an array and load each one into the empty array I just created

```
i=0
for array in directory:
    OG = loadmat(array, appendmat = True) #load the mat file
    OG = OG['new_OG'] #get the actual image from the list
    OG =np.array(OG) #convert to an array
    img_array[i] = OG #append to the empty array
```

However, when I try to append it to `img_array` in the last line, it doesn't work because of the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (80,84,80) into shape (80,84,80,1)
```

So how can I make sure I turn the .mat file into a numpy array with the shape I need: (x,y,z,1)?

Comment: Don't use `ndarray` to create array. `np.array` and `np.zeros` are the normal tools.  You  shouldn't need the `np,array(OG)` step.  Check OG's type, shape and dtype first.  It's easy to add a dimension to an array if needed.  lok up `reshape`

Comment: I looked up reshape, it did the job. Thanks for that :)